# Intellij IDEA EAP Download

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA has EAP program as of my understanding provides the IDE currently building for free. This can have lot of issues. Where can i download this ? The download links in the EAP page download the ultimate edition which need licence or 30 day evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this, what you're looking for?

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP

EAP is not a free licensing program. It's just an early adopter program for the customers. You need a license, anyway.

Comment: I downloaded the linux version installed it. It also request for licence or 30 day evaluation.

Comment: EAP is not a free licensing program. It's just an early adopter program for the customers. You need a license, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think i was misunderstand the EAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the EAP builds from

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Latest+builds

Answer (score 0):

13.1 EAP needs an existing license for 13 indeed

when EAP for *major* version is active, an evaluation license is bundled